# Password length minimum: 7. Non-alphanumeric characters required: 1

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.Net Membership, while creating user wizard I am getting the following error.

Password length minimum: 7. Non-alphanumeric characters required: 1

I have added the following code in **web.config** file inside the Account folder

```
type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
connectionStringName="Developer"
enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
enablePasswordReset="true"
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
applicationName="UsingMembership"
requiresUniqueEmail="false"
minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
passwordFormat="Hashed"
maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
passwordAttemptWindow="10"
passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
```

What met be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could try changing minRequiredPasswordLength to 7, and specifying a regex that requires at least one non alpha character...

Use the following `[^\w]`

This should do it.

Comment: Thanks I will try that, if it fixed my problem I will accept it as best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make the changes to the settings in the web.config in the root of the site, that is where they are read from.

Comment: It can also be helpful